# wait for iframe to load in php

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I read a lot on this forum but couldn't find what I need.

I'm trying to use a php script to clean a desknow database, I managed to make it loop through all my recording and sending the command to an iframe but my issue is that I need it to wait until the iframe as finish loading before it does the next loop since it's sending a database command to the desknow server. I tried to had a sleep in the loop but when I do so it will just wait for the time a specify time the number of loop and then output all iframe at the same time. It does not have to open a new iframe for each record like it's doing here if there is a way to make it just change the src of the iframe on each loop it would be even better.

```
<?php
   echo "start";

    @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'desknow', 'xxxxxxxx', 'desknow');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "fail";
        exit;
   }

    echo "pass";

    for ($i=1; $i <4; $i++) {
        flush();
        sleep(2);   
        $query = "select email from compte where no = $i";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        $row= $result->fetch_assoc();
        $email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['email']));
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<iframe onload=\"load()\" src=\"http://0.0.0.0:81/desknow/admin?pwd=xxxxxx&action=mail_deleteemails&username=$email&domain=mydomain.com&path=inbox&before=20121231_1300/\"></iframe>";
    }

    $result->free();
   $db->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is unsafe, should be considered a very bad practice!

Comment: try using `file_get_contents` or `curl`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ob_flush();` before `flush();` , and `echo 'start';`

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has the IP, username and password of your database server – this is very unsafe and really bad practise.

If you really want to update things like that you need to do it client side.  It would be quite simple to have a javascript method that will reload the HTML content of an existing DOM member.

You could also use a page refresh or a form post to complete another round trip to the server which would update the view.